# bootstrap $(#myModal).modal({show:true}) is not working

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

i am new in php and bootstrap when I trigger the modal using .modal method it doesn't  work

PHP code

```
 if ($show_login_modal) {
     echo " <script>
            $('#loginModal').modal({show:true});
            </script>";
 }
```

Comment: $('#loginModal').modal("show"); try this

Comment: also please check whether a script is Enabled ?

Comment: @NanThiyagan suggestion should work, just make sure you called the jquery library before the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php if ($show_login_modal) { ?>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $('#loginModal').modal({
          show: true
         });
        </script>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: It depends on where you place this code fragment within the HTML output.

One of these solutions, I think, should work:

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue few days ago, this always works

in HTML I made a button , made it **display None using style**

```
<input type="button" value="0"  id="showLogin" style="display:none;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal" />
```

later in script used jquery click(), and done in your case it will be like :

```
 if ($show_login_modal) {
 echo " <script>
       $( "#showLogin" ).click();
        </script>"; }
```

**see if your $show_login_modal *is true then* script will click on hidden button and Modal will appear by that click, simple**